# Trying to run a shellscript but not workung

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, cronjob

My shell script is running when I manually run it. Cronjob is also working, al others are running but not this script.
This is my code.

```
30 3 * * * cd /var/www/html/cronjob && sh shellscript.sh >> testlog.log
```

Comment: `30 3 * * * /var/www/html/cronjob/shellscript.sh >> testlog.log` Write the cronjob like this and check once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with the local timezone and server timezone.